# Создать файл / папку

Tags: java, android, файлы

Как я могу создать папку или файл с текущей датой и временем в определенном каталоге?

````
LocalDateTime ldtFile = LocalDateTime.parse(fileName, f) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo") ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(z) ;
LocalDateTime ldtThreeDaysAgo = zdtNow.minusDays(3).toLocalDateTime() ;

if(ldtFile.isAfter(ldtThreeDaysAgo)) 
{
     ....
}```
Я пробовал этот пример, но у меня не получилось, как для Java 8+.
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте это

```
public static String ArchiveDir;
        
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf.applyPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
        File sdPath = new File(AppPathData() + "/Archive/" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        sdPath.mkdirs();
        ArchiveDir = sdPath.getAbsolutePath();
        return ArchiveDir;
```